# How can I detect if the checkbox created from setCheckable( True ) in a QStandardItem is checked or unchecked?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QStandardItem with setCheckable equal to True.

Any time this QStandardItem is checked or unchecked, I need to be able to have code execute.

How can I do this?

This needs to occur at **ANY** time, so please don't reply with something like checkState() because the check needs to occur as soon as the box is clicked.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

A possible initial solution is to use the `itemChanged` signal as shown below:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        tableview = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.setCentralWidget(tableview)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        tableview.setModel(self.model)

        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)

        for letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(letter)
            it.setCheckable(True)
            self.model.appendRow(it)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QStandardItem*")
    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print("checked")
        else:
            print("unchecked")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it has a drawback: `itemChanged` is emitted before any change, for example when changing the text, color, etc. of the item. So if you want to perform an action when only the state of the checkbox changes then you can use a role to save the previous state then compare the information:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

LastState = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        tableview = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.setCentralWidget(tableview)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        tableview.setModel(self.model)

        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)

        for letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(letter)
            it.setData(it.checkState(), LastState)
            it.setCheckable(True)
            self.model.appendRow(it)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QStandardItem*")
    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        last_state = item.data(LastState)
        current_state = item.checkState()

        if last_state != current_state:
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                print("checked")
            else:
                print("unchecked")

        item.setData(current_state, LastState)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When I try to run the line with self.model.itemChanged, no matter whether or not I set that kind of command to the model or the actual QStandardItem, I always get an AttributeError saying itemChanged, stateChanged, etc. does not exist.  What am I doing wrong? Also I don't know what @ commands do.  Actually there seems to be a LOT going on here that I have no clue what is hapenning.

Comment: @gd197634f21g3f First try my code as it is and inform me if it works for you, if it works just try to apply it to your code, if you have problems with the application to your code then you must provide a [mre] otherwise it is impossible to help you

Comment: @gd197634f21g3f again: mmm, as I pointed out without an MRE it is impossible for me to help you.

Comment: @gd197634f21g3f No, I want you to copy your code because if you had used my code like this you should have no problems, and I do not want you to copy it in the comments but add it to your question. Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the itemChanged signal to a function to handle any change to the item, and in that function check the state of it. This requires your items to be stored in a model, docs [here.](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html)